# Laravel Chat Website stopped due to "Process Limit"

Tags: laravel, process, chat, hosting

I have a website where a **user can chat** with each other and daily maximum visitor is 1000 and typically it is 400-500.
I've added the chat system like **sending a message** to one user to another user.

But today my website was not loading [one specific page] and then I contacted with the Hosting provider [I'm using HostGator reseller package] and they told me  I "**reached the process limit**".

> How can I reduce my processes in the query and use it efficiently? 
>   What is the best way to build chat system with the social profile?

:)

Comment: Are you on a VPS or Shared Hosting Server?

Comment: shared hosting I guess. Its reseller account in HostGator. And also it is HDD, not SSD

Comment: They definitely limiting you then, I would suggest go to AWS or DigitalOcean and configure your own VPS which then you have full control over.

Comment: Agreed. You're only in for more headaches. Follow some nice guides on setting up and securing your own VPS with Digital Ocean and never look back until you're ready to go Enterprise with AWS or Google Cloud or something.